# Attach emulated serial port to software and get results

Tags: serial-port, command

I want to get comport  on my PC without connecting any peripheral device and outputs from there like some device attached to that port. Can any software do that or commands can do that for me?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) you can find a free application which can emulate unlimited number of ports and send one port output to another's input.